# Class is undefined in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with `nodejs` `mysql` library. I wanted to write synchronous queries without callback hell. I found [this](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b) tutorial which talks about promisifying the database client.

Following the tutorial I did:

```
class Database {
    constructor( config ) {
         this.pool = mysql.createPool({
            connectionLimit: 10,
            host: keys.connection.host,
            user: keys.connection.user,
            password: keys.connection.password,
            database: keys.connection.database,
            dateStrings: true                       
        })
    }
    query( sql, args ) {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve( rows );
            } );
        } );
    }
    close() {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.end( err => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve();
            } );
        } );
    }
}
```

Doing `database.query('select * from table')` as mentioned in the tutorial gives me database is not defined error.

I also tried adding

```
const db =new Database()

db.query('select * from table')
```

This gives me

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'query' of undefined

Comment: This code looks oversimplified because you're referencing lots of stuff that the code does not initialize or show.  For example, `this connection`.  Where does that come from?  For example, `keys.connection`.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that your constructor isn't really exactly what you show because `db` should not be `undefined` after calling `new Database()` like you show.  So, I think this is an incomplete example.  There's more going on than you show here.

Comment: The `pool` config is working properly because I was using it before. Doing `pool.query('select * from table')`. I just wanted to promisify the client

Comment: Also, there's an [existing module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) that will promisify mysql for you.  And, your promsifying code does not appear to be correctly following the examples [here](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b).  In particular, you're assigning `this.pool`, but attempting to use `this.connection`.  Neither of which causes `db` to be undefined, but is certainly not correct.

Comment: you're assigning `this.pool`,but attempting to use `this.connection`. This was the problem. Now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting my comments into an answer since it solved the problem for you.

Your promsifying code does not appear to be correctly following the examples [here.](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b) In particular, you're assigning `this.pool`, but attempting to use `this.connection`.

That would cause `this.connection` to be `undefined` which would cause the exception you see for "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" when your code tries to use `this.connection.query`.

So, it's likely that `this.connection.query` causes the error, NOT that your class is not defined.

For future reference, you could have found this yourself with some more debugging.  Either step through the code in the debugger and/or set breakpoints to see exactly where the error happens and why or use `console.log()` statements to learn more about what is happening.  This type of basic debugging will enable you to solve these types of issues more quickly.

---

FYI, there's an [existing module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) that will promisify mysql for you if you want something that will do that for you.